# Replacement for x:Bind Working for UWP in UNO Platform but not WASM, Droid, etc

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I am currently trying out Uno Platform with Prism, to see if it's worth migrating a project of mine from WPF to UWP and Uno. I've built this application with the Prism Template.

I've currently run into an issue where I usually assign a region to a ContentControl, by calling the region name by a static that is stored within a class of static region names.

My WPF XAML code, from Shell.xaml:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="0,0,0,11" 
                prismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static blankCore:RegionNames.ContentHeaderRegion}"/>
```

However, this does not work, due to x:Static not existing in UWP (Unknown type 'Static' in XML namespace). Therefore, after looking at some documentation on UWP, I have used x:Bind and now the code looks like this:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="0,0,0,11" 
                prismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Bind blankCore:RegionNames.ContentHeaderRegion}"/>
```

This is compiling and running for UWP, but upon switching to WASM or Android, I get various errors in a generated file:

```
c32.SetBinding(global::Prism.Regions.RegionManager.RegionNameProperty, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding{ Mode = BindingMode.OneTime }.Apply(___b =>  /*defaultBindModeOneTime*/ global::Uno.UI.Xaml.BindingHelper.SetBindingXBindProvider(___b, this, ___ctx => ___ctx is global::BlankApp1.Shared.Views.Shell ___tctx ? (object)(___tctx.global::BlankApp1.Core.RegionNames.AuthenticateRegion) : null, null )));
```

The error is as follows:
[image]

My current static class of RegionNames is as follows:

```
namespace BlankApp1.Core
{
    public class RegionNames
    {
        public static string ContentHeaderRegion = "ContentHeaderRegion";

        /// ...
    }
}
```

Is going with 'x:Bind' the correct way about this and is there a fix for this?
Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: This generally happens when the target type cannot be resolved by the tooling for some reason. Is the file containing `RegionNames` referenced directly or indirectly in the Wasm/android and other project heads ?

Comment: I have checked and the BlankApp1.Droid and BlankApp1.WASM projects are referencing the BlankApp1.Core class library that is shared between those too and BlankApp1.UWP.

RegionNames.cs is in the BlankApp1.Core project.

Comment: This is odd. Could you open an issue on the Uno repository with your blank app ? That will help troubleshoot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by updating the Uno.UI library to 3.5.x or above. I was on 3.0.x